# Lightbox effect opened below fold relocating user to top of page when closed

Tags: css, gallery, lightbox

I'm using [this simple css code](https://codepen.io/ongtiffany/pen/BoOeQV) by Tiffany Ong to generate a lightbox effect for my images. It works fine until I click an image further down [the page](http://relativelyhuman.com/gallery/digital-art2.html#); when I close the lightbox below the fold it brings me back to the top of the page rather than where I left off. Could someone advise me on how to fix this? Code is pasted below.

```css
/*Eliminates padding, centers the thumbnail */

body, html {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
}

/* Styles the thumbnail */

a.lightbox img {
height: 150px;
border: 3px solid white;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
margin: 94px 20px 20px 20px;
}

/* Styles the lightbox, removes it from sight and adds the fade-in transition */

.lightbox-target {
position: fixed;
top: -100%;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Styles the lightbox image, centers it vertically and horizontally, adds the zoom-in transition and makes it responsive using a combination of margin and absolute positioning */

.lightbox-target img {
margin: inherit;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom: 0;
max-height: 0%;
max-width: 0%;
border: 3px solid white;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Styles the close link, adds the slide down transition */

a.lightbox-close {
display: block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: white;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: -80px;
right: 0;
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */

a.lightbox-close:before {
content: "";
display: block;
height: 30px;
width: 1px;
background: black;
position: absolute;
left: 26px;
top:10px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
-o-transform:rotate(45deg);
transform:rotate(45deg);
}

/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */

a.lightbox-close:after {
content: "";
display: block;
height: 30px;
width: 1px;
background: black;
position: absolute;
left: 26px;
top:10px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Uses the :target pseudo-class to perform the animations upon clicking the .lightbox-target anchor */

.lightbox-target:target {
opacity: 1;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

.lightbox-target:target img {
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}

.lightbox-target:target a.lightbox-close {
top: 0px;
}
```